# How to disable MagnificPopup on certain links to images

Tags: magnific-popup

I run my company's website and have created a page where people can go to download our logo in various file types. Users can click and select the file type they need from a  dropdown which then updates the download button href with the corresponding source.  Using HTML5's download attribute, this then should trigger the file to download.  HOWEVER, this is not happening because I have Magnific Popup installed and by default, Magnific Popup will cause any href with images in them to trigger a lightbox for that image.

See the page i'm referring to here: https://outboundengine.com/brand and scroll to the "Logo Suite" section to see what I mean.

So what I need is to bypass the default behavior of Magnific Popup and allow the image file sourced in the href to be downloaded as it would if Magnific Popup were disabled.

I've tried initializing MFP on the button and using disableOn: false like so:

```
$('.brand-logos.horizontal .color a.btn').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: false
});
```

...and it does as intented by disabling the popup, but it still isn't allowing the href to trigger download.  Basically nothing happens and my users aren't able to download the files at all.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?  If i remove Magnific Popup entirely, I can select a file type and click the button and it downloads that file no problem.  It's just with Magnific Popup turned on that it's no longer working.

Comment: trying to do the same here. DId you managed to get a solution?

Comment: Still no solution :(